# Angular - changes detection for object parameters not working

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

I have the following component code.  In my `component.ts` I have defined the following:

```js
  tickets: Ticket[] = []
  uploadCounts: {[key: string]: number} = {}
  
  ngOnInit() { /* Code to grab Tickets from API, init uploadCounts to 0 for each ticket id */ }

  incrementUploadCount(id: string, increment: number) {
    const counts = { ...this.uploadCounts };  // Copy upload counts
    counts[id]+=increment
    this.uploadCounts = { ...counts };  // Clone counts --> new uploadCounts
    console.log(this.uploadCounts);     // This properly logs the uploadCounts changes, in realtime, but
                                        // results are still not updated in the template.
    this.cdr.detectChanges();           // Manually detect changes
  }

  addFile(ticket: Ticket, file) {
    this.incrementUploadCount(ticket.id, 1);  // Increment the upload count by 1 for this ticket.
    this.ticketSvc.uploadFile(ticket, file).then(res => {
        this.incrementUploadCount(ticket.id, -1);  // Decrease the upload count by 1 for this ticket.
    });
  }
```

And in my `component.html` I have:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="ticket of tickets">
  <h2>{{ ticket.name }}</h2>
  <div *ngIf="uploadCounts[ticket.id] > 0">Uploading {{ uploadCounts[ticket.id] }} files...</div>
</ng-container>
```

When `addFile` is triggered, the file is added, however the upload counts div for that ticket is not shown, nor updated until after everything is complete (when it flashes up for a few milliseconds and disappears).  I have been careful to make sure that the entire `uploadCounts` object is overwritten with each change in upload status so that changes are detected (see the `incrementUploadCount` method).  All of the other questions I've found on SO showed that to be the issue, but it doesn't seem to have any effect here.  Any thoughts on why this might be happening or a better way to go about this?

Note: there are multiple tickets being displayed on the page, and each ticket could have multiple uploads going on, thus the need for some sort of indexing of which tickets have an upload in progress).

Comment: Can you recreate it on Stackblitz?

Comment: I can try. It is part of a very large app, so I need to go through and pull out/scaffold out some services.  Will update the post if I can get something working on Stackblitz.